# When to use 'uses' and 'usage'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I find the words 'uses' and 'usage' confusing. Most of the times, I fail to use them correctly. Can someone please tell me when to use them. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Kirti, can you explain what you think is the same or different about them, and how you are confused?  As the question stands, it looks like checking a dictionary would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*usage* is a noun, and *use* besides being a noun, it's also a verb. (When you *use* something, it's for you to employ it in some purpose. The *usage* is the customary way of doing something.) For instance,

> I often use a pan to cook.
>   <s>I often usage a pan to cook.</s>
>   The daily usage that you give to that pan is perfect.

Comment: Meanings, please?