# Can 'computer use' and 'computer usage' be used interchangeably in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

*Context:* In my IELTS class, I have to rewrite this sentence using a different structure:

> There will be a sharp increase in **the use of computers in classroom** by
> the next decade.

---

My answer was:

> By the next decade, **computer usage in classroom** will grow
> tremendously.

and the Answer Key was:

> **Classroom computer use** will increase sharply by the next decade.

---

Did I use the word 'usage' correctly? Does my answer sound right and natural with you native speakers? Can 'use' and 'usage' be used interchangeably in this case?

I have looked up the 2 words in dictionaries and read this link as a reference but I still can't really tell what's right or wrong: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34712/use-vs-usage/34714#34714

Thank you!

Comment: I can't explain why [in the specific context of ***computer** use / usage*,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=computer+use+will+increase%2Ccomputer+usage+will%2Cwater+use+will+increase%2Cwater+usage+will+increase&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) the latter is apparently far more common. But as you'll see from that linked chart, we much prefer ***water use*** over ***...usage***, and it's the same story with ***energy use***. I think perhaps computer nerds just like "fancy" words, but my advice is to stick with plain and simple ***use*** everywhere.

Comment: Wooah, thank you for your answer, the link and the advice (i will do that!!)! I didn't know about this cool Google tool, so ty again!!

Comment: I commend the earlier questions ["use" vs. "usage" in "The use / usage of a different drug calls for a detailed justification"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116024/) and [When to use 'uses' and 'usage'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76679/). ["Usage" versus "use"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4534/usage-versus-use) has more votes, but I can't endorse it because the top-rated answer endorses using ***usage*** in contexts where I feel it's unnecessary. Particularly in advice for *learners*, I think we should always favour the simplest "acceptable" form.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, ["computer **use** will" is in fact more common than "computer **usage** will"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=computer+use+will%2Ccomputer+usage+will%2Cwater+use+will+increase%2Cwater+usage+will+increase&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).  Your chart has an added condition **increase** applied to the **use** case and hence the skewed result.

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore: Oh! Thanks for the explanation. I don't know how I missed that, but [the chart I intended to show](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=computer+use+will+increase%2Ccomputer+usage+will+increase%2Cwater+use+will+increase%2Cwater+usage+will+increase&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) clearly reflects the point I was making. With the *correct* set of 4 search strings, Google NGrams explicitly says "Ngrams not found: **computer usage will increase**".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why does the expression with "usage" appear to be significantly more popular than the version with "use"? [**computer usage will be** vs **computer use will be**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=computer+use+will+be%2C+computer+usage+will+be&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Because the NGram I linked to in my first comment erroneously omits the word ***increase*** after search string ***computer usage will***. But since that additional constraint isn't in the *other* three search strings (including ***computer use will increase***), it gave a misleading result. In reality, ***use*** is far more common than ***usage*** for computers, energy, water, and probably *every* credible "noun representing a thing that can be used or consumed".

Answer (score 2):

You used *usage* correctly! Probably the answer key had a different response because the writer was trying to keep the two sentences as similar as possible. Your sentence had the same meaning, but slightly different words.

In general, *usage* and *use* (as a noun) are the same word and can be used in the same way. In the past, *usage* was a noun and *use* was only a verb. Over time, language changed and now they can both be nouns.

### Articles

I would make one change to the starter sentence and your sentence though. These would sound more correct if there was an article or qualifier before the word *classroom* OR if classroom was plural instead (*classrooms*). So I would write this as "*By the next decade, computer usage in the classroom will grow tremendously.*"

I recently wrote [another answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/347189/why-the-teacher-but-not-necessarily-the-students/347196#347196) about articles and why this is more correct.